# Visual Studio Compiler is highlighting Static variables differently?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-variables

I'm programming in C++ and have a method which uses a static variable. The method isn't working as I think it should; upon investigation, I found that my static variable is being highlighted in red in two places and blue in other places. Below is the code:

```
int GameModeState::changeJob(int number)
{
    static int job = 1; //red
    if (number == 1)
    {
        job = (job+1); //First one is red, second one is blue
        return job; //blue
    } else {
        return job; //blue
    }
}
```

I'm calling this method with other methods, one shown for example:

```
int GameModeState::getJob()
{
    int currentJob = (changeJob(2));
    return currentJob;
}
```

I want a method like `getJob()` to simply return the current value of `job`, while another method, when calling changeJob(number) is `changeJob(1)`, to increment job's value by one. (Hence the if/else statement in `changeJob(number)`). 
Since the `job` variables are highlighted differently, I'm thinking the compiler is saying that it views the two separately somehow? I'm getting stuck with `job` being some even value.

**EDIT** I also have Awesomium... I believe that is the only addition to the compiler, but I'm not completely sure.

**MOAR EDIT** In another class, I have a method which should determine the current job's number and do something based on if the number is even or odd (since right now there are only two jobs)

```
void ZoneMovementState::_changeZone(const String& message, const Awesomium::JSValue& input, Awesomium::JSValue& output)
{
    //Awesomium::JSValue::Object object = input.getObject();
    //String zoneFilename = Convert::toString(object[L"zoneFilename"].toString());

    // If the number from getJob is even, the player is currently a geologist
    if (GameModeState::getJob()%2 == 0)
    {
        ZoneParser::getSingleton().load("../media/zones/geology_zone.xml", false);
    } else {
        ZoneParser::getSingleton().load("../media/zones/farm_zone.xml", false);
    }
    transitionHandler->go();
}
```

Ignore the two commented out lines; they deal with JS, which I'm not working on for now.
In the program, I can access the `farm_zone` until I increment job's value using the below method in `GameModeState`:

```
    void GameModeState::_openNotebook(const String& message, const Awesomium::JSValue& input, Awesomium::JSValue& output)
{
    mNotebookTransition->go();
    static int currentJob = changeJob(1);
}
```

.... So I figured out my problem. While going through the code to show you guys, I realized that the static for `currentJob` was probably unneeded... once I removed it, my code works as it should now.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Why're you using a local static variable and not a class member variable?

Comment: Because I don't know what member variables are? I'm a novice C++ programmer.

Comment: Visual Studio shouldn't highlight either of these.  What pulgin's do you have installed?

Comment: Doesn't a static variable keep it's value throughout the entire program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is you're using a static local for what very likely should just be a member variable.  A static local maintains it's value across all calls to a function in all threads in a process.  It's much more likely that you want it to persist for all calls to `changeJob` in a particular `GameModeState` instance (else why make it a member functon to begin with?).

To do this you'll need to define a member variable on `GameModeState` initialize it in the constructor and then access it in the method.  For example

```
class GameModeState {
  int job;
  GameModeState() : job(1) {} 
  int changeJob(int number);
};

int GameModeState::changeJob(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        job = (job+1);
        return job;
    } else {
        return job;
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not entirely sure why you're seeing the color's your are seeing.  Visual Studio by default won't color member variables a particular color in C++ so it's very likely another add-in you are using.

Comment: Well, I'm wanting to get the value of job from another class. I'm not sure if GameModeState is "one instance" or recreated every time it's activated (working with a company on a 3D game... very complex classes which were built before I got here). That's why I was trying to use a static variable, since it seems they are almost like global variables

Comment: @Briz a member variable is a 'per instance' variable.  If you want to share a variable amongst instances then a static is your best bet.  However you likely want a static member instead of a static local.  Can you tell us a bit more what this variable is meant to do?

Comment: Asking for more explaination led me to find the error in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nah, highlighting doesn't mean anything. That is, the editor doesn't call the compiler before deciding how/what/when to highlight. So that is not your problem. Sorry 'bout that :-)

You can prove this to yourself by going to Tools->Options->TextEditor and noticing that you can change the highlighting by choosing a different text-editing model.